# Prove that the limit of $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}$ is $\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let 
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt\frac{1}{n^2+k^2}$$Prove that the limit of the sequence  {$a_n$} is $\ln(1+\sqrt{2})$

Comment: Have you heard of Riemann sums?

Comment: This is a series, not a sequence of series.

Comment: Hint:-put limit as n tends to infinity $a_n$then use integral as limit of sums to get the answer.

Comment: Yes,i have thought use of integral;but i could not write its function.Also i have a question about use of integral:When we use integral we consider all the real numbers of domain but in sequences our domain consists of just positive integers.So,is not there something wrong?

Comment: You will probably need here inverse hyperbolic functions

Comment: @RexViridis Is it correct .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by factoring an $n^2$ out of the denominator, to get
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}}
$$

To me, this looks like we've taken $[0,1]$ and broken it down into $n$ pieces $[0,\tfrac{1}{n}]$, $(\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac{2}{n}]$, etc.

In this context, if we were setting up a Riemann sum for an integral, we would have $\Delta x=\frac{1}{n}$, and $x_i=\frac{k}{n}$ (where we commit the usual abuses of notation taught in integral calculus).  So, we could rewrite your sum as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+x_i^2}}\,\Delta x.
$$
Is it clear, in this form, what integral this Riemann sum would represent?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

then

$$a_n=\frac{1-0}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(0+\frac{k(1-0)}{n})$$

$f$ is continuous at $[0,1]$ thus

$$L=\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_n=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

with the change $x=sh(t)$, we get

$L=argsh(1)$ and

$$\frac{(e^L-e^{-L})}{2}=1$$

which becomes

$$e^{2L}-2e^L-1=0.$$

thus

$e^L=1+\sqrt{2}$ and finally

$$\color{green}{L=Log(1+\sqrt{2}).}$$